# Azure AD OAuth2.0: I dont get a refresh token

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

when a client application (such as a webpage using our api) is connecting to a Azure AD OAuth2.0-protected web api

To get the access token, the client applications make a POST to this
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token

But the client applcation does not get a refresh token.Is that not needed in the "client application" scenario?

This is what they get

```
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": "3600",
"ext_expires_in": "0",
"expires_on": "1531906803",
"not_before": "1531902903",
"resource": "https://our-api.azurewebsites.net",
"access_token": "YtNGEzZi1hZGYyLTExNjU4N......rdFqQ"
```

The token works fine and it SEEMS that it never expires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you got the token with client credentials (client id + client secret or certificate), then you don't get a refresh token.
In this scenario, you can always get a new access token with the application's credentials alone, so you do not need refresh tokens.

In the case of flows which have user context, you get a refresh token since you cannot repeat the user login at will, and must use the refresh token to get a fresh token.

Comment: Aha, Thanks! But will the token expire? (Im writing an instruction to my clients and need to know this and if so, what will the api return (when called with an expired token )?

Comment: Yes, by default they expire in 1 hour. What the API returns depends on how it is configured if the token is expired. Usually they return a 401. You can see in the token response how many seconds it is valid though (`expires_in`), so you can keep track of that yourself if desired.

Comment: Ok, I have a made a request with postman now, will try hitting my api in over an hour and view the results. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *you can always get a new access token with the application's credentials alone, so you do not need refresh tokens* is this by navigating users to the /redirect again or are you supposed to make a request to authorize/token endpoint?

Comment: No, that's referring to client credentials flow where a user is not involved at any point. In that flow the app can always get a token from the token endpoint whenever it wants using its credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need add a special scope `offline_access` when you request `authorization_code` to receive `refresh_token` as the result. Check it out, may be it is you case :)

Comment: Please add documentation for referal. Your answer without documentation is of no help at all...

Comment: I found this documentation link for refreshing tokens
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#refresh-auth-tokens